# Como insertar 100 registros en una tabla de SQL Server al mismo tiempo

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

¿me podrían apoyar?. Necesito insertar 100 registros al mismo tiempo en una tabla de usuarios y se que se puede realizar mediante una query, lamentablemente no se mucho de SQL como para realizarlo asi e insertar de uno en uno seria muy tardado.

La tabla contiene estos campos

```
UsuarioId   Numcontrol   Nombre   Apellido
```

Comment: Hola Programador S. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola @lois6b creo que el foro es para eso, pedir ayuda acerca de lo que no sabes, te agradezco tu comentario, pero si no vas a realizar una aportación que me ayude preferiría leer a quien si lo hace, muchas gracias.

Comment: @ProgramadorS Este sitio sirve para hacer preguntas sobre programación, no para que te hagan el trabajo. Revisate [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para saber como realizar una buena pregunta.

Comment: Hola Programador. Primero, este sitio no es un **foro** ya que no cumple la finalidad de charla abierta si no un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Segundo, estoy haciendo una aportacion. Una aportacion para que mejores la pregunta acorde a la calidad necesaria para que siga abierta. Aqui se puede pedir ayuda pero sobre lo que se ha trabajado previamente. Por supuesto te vamos a ayudar si muestras qué problemas exactos has tenido. Pero como te digo, has de **intentarlo** buscando información primero. Un saludo

Comment: Tal y como dice @Marc acá no hacemos tareas, ayudamos a resolver problemas específicos que se pueden encontrar al desarrollar, para poderte ayudar tienes que intentarlo primero y decirnos específicamente en que parte te pegaste. Son críticas constructivas para que mejores tu productividad en este sitio, saludos.

Comment: vuelvo a enfatizar, recibí bastante ayuda y eso es suficiente para mi, sea o no un foro, aclare el punto -no se realizar algo.
En fin aprecio leer comentarios de quien si me ayudo a resolver mi problema, que considero, si,  no es complicado, pero si algo que hace 10 minutos atrás desconocía, ahora con la ayuda de varias respuestas útiles se como realizar. Gracias

Comment: Puede ser sufiente para tí pero no es suficiente para el sitio. Ahora puedes haber aprendido cómo se hace pero te aseguro que aprenderás más y tendrás mucha más satisfacción aprendiendo si te peleas con el problema antes de decir "no sé". Un saludo

Comment: @ProgramadorS Primero debes respetar las normas del sitio y ya despues respetando eso publicas tus preguntas, pero no al revés como has hecho. Buscando en Google habrias obtenido el mismo resultado y encima lo habrias resuelto tu sólo.

Comment: creo que la discusión viene ya sin sentido. Hay mas de una respuesta debajo de mi pregunta. al inicio pregunte claramente si me podrían apoyar. Estoy de acuerdo con sus puntos sobre la forma de realizar mi pregunta, sin embargo me queda claro que hay mas de una persona aquí que si esta dispuesta a aclarar cualquier duda. No solo venir a discutir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias hacerlo de multiples formas :

**Directa**

```
INSERT INTO mi_tabla ( columna1, columna2 ) VALUES
( Valor1, Valor2 ), ( Valor1, Valor2 )
```

**ejemplo:**

```
INSERT INTO mi_tabla ( columna1, columna2, columna3 )
VALUES ('John', 123, 'Mexico'), 
('Juan', 124, 'Italia'), 
('Bily', 125, 'Londres'),
('Miranda', 126, 'Belgica');
```

**mediante un while**

```
declare @id int 
select @id = 1
while @id >=1 and @id <= 100
begin
    insert into estudiantes values(@id, 'estudiante_' + convert(varchar(5), @id), 12)
    select @id = @id + 1
end
```

En este metodo  lo que hace es insertar datos directamente, tanto el id , como el nombre..

Comment: Gracias por responder pero hacerle la tarea ayuda menos al usuario que esperar a ver cual es su problema particular y ayudarle sobre ello. Recuerda que no todas las preguntas se deben responder. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b en realidad recibi bastante ayuda, no pido que me hagan ninguna tarea ni ningun trabajo, pido la ayuda porque en realidad no se como crear una query en sql. No es mucha la experiencia que tengo, gracias.

Comment: @ProgramadorS pero has de intentarlo y mostrar tu duda exacta. con tarea me refiero a tu necesidad de meter X usuarios en la tabla. con duda, pues algo del estilo *"la consulta `insert into` me da fallo porque ... etc"* . Mira los enlaces de [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score -1):

Además de las respuestas que te han dado, si los datos los tienes en otra tabla, puedes hacer un

**INSERT INTO SELECT**

```
INSERT INTO Tabla1 (UsuarioId, Numcontrol, Nombre, Apellido)
SELECT (columna1, columna2, columna3, columna4)
FROM Tabla2
WHERE condiciones
```

Comment: Gracias por responder pero hacerle la tarea ayuda menos al usuario que esperar a ver cual es su problema particular y ayudarle sobre ello. Recuerda que no todas las preguntas se deben responder. Un saludo